# How to deploy an image after its nodejs version is changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to deploy this image to the aws lambda https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/552623489034/amplify-passwordless-sms-auth But it is getting failed so i went to the git hub of the repo and i saw that the bug which i am getting is already reported  which is here https://github.com/mobilequickie/amplify-passwordless-sms-auth/issues/47 I have cloned the image and created a new branch for the same with the fix that is being mentioned on the github issue. Now how will i deploy the same?